# SQL Insert trigger to update INSERTED table values

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, triggers

I want to create an Insert trigger that updates values on all the inserted rows if they're null, the new values should be taken from a different table, according to another column in the inserted table.

I tried:

```
UPDATE INSERTED
SET TheColumnToBeUpdated = 
    (
    SELECT TheValueCol FROM AnotherTable.ValueCol
    WHERE AnotherTable.ValudCol1 = INSERTED.ValueCol1
    )
WHERE ValueCol IS NULL
```

But I get this error:

```
Msg 286, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ThisTable_INSERT, Line 15
The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated.
```

How should I do that?

Comment: If you aren't going to encapsulate the logic to handle this in a stored procedure, a better alternative than a trigger would be to use a default constraint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Shimmy can't use a default as per the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744455

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to update the destination table, not the logical table. You join with the logical table, though, to figure out which rows to update:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET TheColumnToBeUpdated = 
    (
    SELECT TheValueCol FROM AnotherTable.ValueCol
    WHERE AnotherTable.ValudCol1 = INSERTED.ValueCol1
    )
FROM YourTable Y
JOIN Inserted I ON Y.Key = I.Key
WHERE I.ValueCol IS NULL
```

Comment: (I know that this is very old!) Won't this update all the rows in YourTable? Adding the following to the final "where" clause will update just the row that was inserted: "and Y.Key = I.Key".

Comment: @AndyKing `JOIN Inserted I ON Y.Key = I.Key` will restrict the update to just the inserted row/rows

Answer (score 23):

You could change the trigger to an INSTEAD OF INSERT. This will let you check the incoming values and, if needed replace them with the values from your other table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CoolTrigger 
ON MyAwesomeTable 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN  

INSERT MyAwesomeTable (TheValueCol)
SELECT ISNULL(INSERTED.TheValueCol, AnotherTable.TheValueCol) AS TheValueCol
FROM INSERTED
JOIN AnotherTable ON INSERTED.ValueCol1 = AnotherTable.ValueCol1

END
```

NOTE: INSTEAD OF triggers do NOT cause recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into output  
(SELECT t1.ts - INTERVAL (SECOND(t1.ts)%10) SECOND,  
t1.ts - INTERVAL (SECOND(t1.ts)%10) SECOND + INTERVAL 10 SECOND ,sum(t1.data),   
FROM (select * from input   
where unix_timestamp(ts) >= unix_timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:10')  
and unix_timestamp(ts) < unix_timestamp('2000-01-01 00:01:20')  
)
  as t1   
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.ts) DIV 10 );
```

This is where my output table is coming from.
So the insertion is not by values.

Im so sorry but I can't access my account from here (office),