# SQL Trigger for ONLY currently inserted row

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a Trigger, MyTrigger, I want to make that ONLY changes the DESCRIPTION FIELD, [Description], of the recently inserted row in TABLEA. As shown, I have the basics of it but it will currently will just scan the entire table for every INSERT on TABLEA.

TRIGGER IS BELOW.............

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger  
   ON  TABLEA
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE TABLEA
SET [DESCRIPTION] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([DESCRIPTION], '…' , '...'),'–','-'),'’',''''),'½','1/2'),'•','+'),'”','"'),'“','"'),'‘',''''),'—','-'),'é','e')
WHERE  DESCRIPTION LIKE '%…%' 
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%–%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%½%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%•%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%”%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%“%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%‘%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%—%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%é%'

END
GO
```

Comment: I guessed at the database type. Please make sure you include that in your tags when you post. (Use the edit link right below the tags to correct if that was not what you use.)

Comment: Read about [how to create a trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and make sure to read the part about the `Inserted` logical table that's available to you inside your trigger code - it will contain exactly those rows that have been inserted. ....

Comment: Very closely related to [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837475/sql-insert-trigger-to-update-inserted-table-values) that updates the record(s) that was/were just inserted

Comment: As an aside, the following should be equivalent to your entire series of `DESCRIPTION LIKE …`: `DESCRIPTION LIKE '%[…–’½•”“‘—é]%'`.

Comment: While your following marc_s' suggestion, also note that triggers work on rowsets, i.e. sometimes users alter more than a single row.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing this in an `INSTEAD` OF trigger, thus only actually performing one DDL action against the table (you can also ignore the `WHERE` clause here and just apply the replace calls to everything in `inserted`).

```
DROP TRIGGER MyTrigger ON TABLEA;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger  
   ON  TABLEA
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT TABLEA(col1, col2, ..., Description)
    SELECT col1, col2, ...,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([DESCRIPTION], '…' , '...'),'–','-'),'’','''')
    ,'½','1/2'),'•','+'),'”','"'),'“','"'),'‘',''''),'—','-'),'é','e')
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

why you are not using tables like `INSERTED` AND `DELETED` rather than scanning whole table and updating last record ....

check this : [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: They're actually more *logical* or *conceptual* rather than *magic* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `inserted` table and make the trigger `INSTEAD OF` not `AFTER` (example follows).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE     @temp       table   --temp table that can be modified
(
    Column1
    , Column1
    , Column1
    , [DESCRIPTION]     --this table should mimic your TABLEA schema
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT      *
FROM        inserted

UPDATE @temp
SET [DESCRIPTION] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([DESCRIPTION], '…' , '...'),'–','-'),'’',''''),'½','1/2'),'•','+'),'”','"'),'“','"'),'‘',''''),'—','-'),'é','e')
WHERE  DESCRIPTION LIKE '%…%' 
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%–%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%½%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%•%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%”%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%“%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%‘%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%—%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%é%'


INSERT INTO TABLEA
            (
                Column1
                , Column1
                , Column1
                , [DESCRIPTION]
            )
SELECT      Column1
            , Column1
            , Column1
            , [DESCRIPTION]
FROM        @temp

END
GO
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot **update** the `Inserted` (or `Deleted`) logical tables - they are to be treated as read-only tables

Comment: rechecked the docs, you are correct. Updated code to use a temp table instead.

Comment: Don't think you really need a @temp table and an update. Why not just apply the replace during the insert? This seems like a lot of extra I/O for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to last line in code - change Identifier with your table's Unique identifier / (Primary Key ?).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger  
   ON  TABLEA
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE TABLEA
SET [DESCRIPTION] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([DESCRIPTION], '…' , '...'),'–','-'),'’',''''),'½','1/2'),'•','+'),'”','"'),'“','"'),'‘',''''),'—','-'),'é','e')
WHERE  (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%…%' 
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%–%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%’%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%½%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%•%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%”%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%“%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%‘%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%—%'
    OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%é%')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted i WHERE i.Identifier = TableA.Identifier)

END
GO
```