# SQL - Setting parameters for Default Column Value in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, column-defaults

Using SQL Server 2012.

I have a column in my member table that is created using the following script:

```
[EnableMemberWebAccess] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1))
```

I want this column to only have 1 as a default if another column in this same table is a certain value. Let's call this column MemDesc, and I want the EnableMemberWebAccess to be defaulted to 1 when MemDesc = 'Founder', and for it to default to 0 when MemDesc != 'Founder'.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you need to write a trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744455/using-udf-for-default-value-of-a-column , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402167/use-a-udf-as-the-default-value-in-a-table-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no way to achieve a default value that can be changed afterwards. Either you have a value that you insert in the beginning. You will then need to take care of consistency within the application:

```
ALTER TABLE *table* ADD COLUMN EnableMemberWebAccess bit NULL

UPDATE *table* SET *table.*EnableMemberWebAccess = CAST(CASE WHEN *table*.MemDesc = 'Founder' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)

ALTER TABLE *table* ALTER COLUMN EnableMemberAccess bit NOT NULL
```

Or you have to use a computed column. This will not allow you to change the value of the column except if you change the value of the column it depends on.

Comment: This will be a one time update whereas the question talks about default value to the column. How will this cater for new records inserted after the update?

Comment: After the update it will not do anything, other than fail. I think there is no way of doing what the op asked. At least I do not know of any way. Providing consistency of the column should be done on the application level, not on the database. If the value should be the same all along, a calculated column would be needed.

Comment: @Amit Sukralia What the question asks cannot be done by a calculated column. A calculated column will not be modifiable. A default value is. However a default value cannot depend on another column, as far as I know.

Comment: Try the code that I have given in my answer and that should show that it works. What do you mean by "A calculated column will not be modifiable".

Comment: @AmitSukralia I cannot do "UPDATE *table* SET EnableMemberWebAccess  = 1 WHERE *whatever*

Comment: Yes you are correct - It will not be updateable. However, is that even required. I would assume that `EnableMemberWebAccess` will always be dependent on `MemDesc`. Therefore, whenever there is a change in the value of `MemDesc`, `EnableMemberWebAccess` should change accordingly. If this is not the expected behaviour then computed column approach will not suffice.

Answer (score -1):

Computed column should work for you:
`ADD EnableMemberWebAccess AS cast((CASE WHEN MemDesc='Founder' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bit)`