# Microsoft SQL Server - default value provided by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to have a non-null column where the value is generated at insert by calling a stored procedure the parameters of which are values passed to insert into the row?

For example, I have table `User`:

```
| username | name | surname | id |
```

Insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO USER (username, name, surname) 
VALUES ('myusername', 'myname', 'mysurname');
```

The `id` column is populated with an (integer) value retrieved by calling stored procedure `mystoredproc` with parameters `myusername`, `myname`, `mysurname`.

A further question is, would this stored procedure be called on each row, or can it be called in a grouped fashion. For example, I'd like my stored procedure to take the `name` and append a random integer to it so that that if I insert 100 users with the name 'David', they will get the same `id` and the stored procedure will be called only once. A bit of a bad example on the second point.

Comment: It would only be possible to insert one row at a time in this manner.

Comment: How would you define column `id`? I can't remember how to define custom logic for a primary key which rather than auto-increments, calls a stored proc. What do I need to google for? Although, column `id` doesn't have to be primary key and in my extension, of course, can't be one.

Comment: What do you mean "how would you define it"?   You said it's an integer.   What more definition does it need?

Comment: If you're ready to google on...  sounds like you want a User Defined Function :)

Comment: @TabAlleman How would you specify, in the table definition, that unless a value is provided at insert for `id`, it needs to call a stored procedure to generate one.

Comment: yes define an IDENTITY on the `id` column and use an UDF to seed it: http://www.itprotoday.com/udfs-provide-new-identity

Comment: Why don't you do it with a table valued function?

Comment: If you use a function instead of a stored procedure, you can call the function in a default constraint:   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163714/in-sql-server-how-do-you-create-a-default-constraint-for-a-column-using-the-res

Comment: Also:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402167/use-a-udf-as-the-default-value-in-a-table-column-in-sql-server

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks. I don't know why this post was voted down if I'm honest.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad design to me. Are you trying to get a row number for each user? It sounds like you want to allow multiple rows for the same user. And when you generate a key like you are doing it is quite likely that you have created a race condition. Consider what happens when multiple people try to enter the same information.

Comment: You probably don't mean "random integer". You could insert a group of rows for "Marvin" and get, at random, "Marvin42". A subsequent insert of "Marvin" could randomly assign "Marvin42" or "Marvin54". Do you want to ensure that the new `id` does not already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

> > Is it possible to have a non-null column where the value is generated at insert by calling a stored procedure

Option 1: please check if this work for you

1. Specify Default Value for the Column and use "NOT NULL"
2. create trigger on the table AFTER INSERT
3. Inside the trigger, you can use the virtual table "inserted" in order to get the inserted values.
4. Using these values (using the inserted table) you can update the column using the logic you need for all the rows at once

** there is no need to use external SP probably, but you can execute SP from trigger if needed

** All executed by a trigger is in the same transaction as the original query.

> > would this stored procedure be called on each row

NO! The trigger will be executed **once** for all rows you insert in the same statement. The inserted table includes all the rows which were inserted. In your update section (step 4) you can update all the rows which were inserted in once and no need to execute something for each row

** If you do use external SP which is executed from the trigger then you can pass it all the inserted table as one [using Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

------------------- update ---------------

Here is a full example of using this logic:

```
drop table if exists T;
CREATE TABLE T (id int identity(2,2), c int NOT NULL default 1)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr ON T AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE T SET T.c = T2.C + 1
    FROM inserted T2
    INNER JOIN T T1 ON T1.id = T2.id

END

INSERT T(c) values (1) -- I insert the value 1 but the trigger will change it to 1+1=2
select * from T
GO

-- test multiple rows:
INSERT T(c) values (10),(20),(30),(40)
select * from T
GO
```

Comment: I agree with other comments that this case sound like a bad design. This solution answer the question, but I highly recommend to think about re-design the system so you will not need to have this requirement/needs

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 0,
  @UserID INT = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 1;

WHILE @rc = 0
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserId= @UserId)
  BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Users(UserId) WHERE Username = @UserName SELECT @UserId;
    SET @rc = 1; 
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT @UserId = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 1,
      @rc = 0;
  END
END
```

Comment: I don't know of such "Insert..... Where".  Is this pseudocode?  But more importantly, I'm not sure how this addresses the requirements...   the OP wants to know how to add logic updating one column based on other columns in a single insert.